# RecyclerView just showing the first element in an ArrayList

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new in Android and I'm figuring out how RecycleView works. For this I had created a simple example project in which I show a list of items. I have the activity_main layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewItems"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I created a list_layout for the elements inside the RecycleView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

With this layouts I had created the Item model like this:

```
data class Item(
    val title: String,
    val description: String
)
```

And I created the adapter for the Item model like this, in a class called ItemsAdapter:

```
class ItemsAdapter(val items: List<Item>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        return ItemViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = items[position]
        holder.view.title.text = item.title
        holder.view.description.text = item.description
    }

    class ItemViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
}
```

Now, in my MainActivity class, I created a ArrayList with Item objects to show in app like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerViewItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val items = ArrayList<Item>()
        items.add(Item("Item 1", "This is the first added item"))
        items.add(Item("Item 2", "This is the second added item"))
        items.add(Item("Item 3", "This is the third added item"))
        recyclerViewItems.adapter = ItemsAdapter(items)
    }
}
```

The problem is when the app runs, the list only show the first element in the array list, is not showing the two left items, why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in recycler view layout file (list_layout). You should set it to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="20dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Description"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It worked :) thanks a lot! As soon as I can accept this as correct answer, I will accept it!